# Re-label the topic number in STM

Tags: r, topic-modeling, topicmodels

For presentation, I would like to re-label the topic number of STM topic modeling (e.g., change 'topic 40' into 'topic 1'). I am however not sure where I should change (where are the topic numbers stored?).

Answer (score 0):

Relabel for what purpose?  Essentially all the plotting functions offer custom labels.  Try the excellent tidystm package (https://github.com/mikaelpoul/tidystm) for even more control over the graphics.

Comment: This is because I do not want to present in my paper that topic 40 and topic 1 are kin topics; rather I want to label them as 'topic 1' and 'topic 2'. But I don't know how to change them.

Comment: There are so many things that plot topics in the package, you have to be more specific.  Assuming you mean plot.STM though here is some sample code of the labeling:
plot(gadarianFit, topic.names=c("My Label:", "My Label2:", "Another Label:"))

Answer (score -1):

Create a vector of custom topic names as desired

```
topicNames<-c("topic 1","topic 2", etc)
```

Then when you plot, use your custom *topicNames* as below

```
plot(x,type="summary",custom.labels="", topic.names=topicNames, ...)
```

Your *topicNames* will Default to the STM "Topic #: ".